# If I have an array of positive and negative values, how do I only keep the positive ones, and replace the negative ones by 0?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have a matrix A with a row of 100 values. When I do

```
B=A(A>=0);
```

My new matrix only has 50 values and I can't plot it anymore, because I need to specifically plot 100 values. How would I keep the placement of the empty values at 0?

Example:

```
 A= [1 -1 2 -2 3 -3]
```

B would have to be

```
B = [1 0 2 0 3 0]
```

Comment: I misunderstood what was asked of me, not needed anymore!

Answer (score 2):

```
B = A;
B(A < 0) = 0;
```

`A < 0` will return a a binary array `[0 1 0 1 0 1]` for your example. Calling `B(A < 0) = 0` will set all positions of `B` with a `1` in `A < 0` to `0`.